# Magento2.4: fatal:no submodule mapping found in .gitmodules for path public_html/vendor/ezyang/htmlpurfier

Tags: magento2, git, linux

On running git pull command, I get this error. Could you please help fix this?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

No submodule mapping was found in .gitmodules for path 'OtherLibrary/MKStore' when

> $ git submodule update --init

I didn't know why the error occur. After spending a minute and I found the answer in StackOverflow:

> $ git rm --cached OtherLibrary/MKStore

and then updated the submodule again. It's working fine.

http://en.saturngod.net/no-submodule-mapping-found-in-gitmodules